# Duplicate pods / Pods creating without deploy existing

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running into an issue managing my Kubernetes pods.

I had a deploy instance which I removed and created a new one. The pod tied to that deploy instance shut down as expected and a new one came up when I created a new deploy, as expected.

However, once I changed the deploy, a second pod began running. I tried to "kubectl delete pod pod-id" but it would just recreate itself again.

I went through the same process again and now I'm stuck with 3 pods, and no deploy. I removed the deploy completely, and I try to delete the pods but they keep recreating themselves. This is an issue because I am exhausting the resources available on my Kubernetes.

Does anyone know how to force remove these pods? I do not know how they are recreating themselves if there's no deploy to go by.

Comment: The root cause could be either an existing deployment, replicaset, daemonset, statefulset or a static pod. Check if any of these exists in the affected namespace using `kubectl get <RESOURCE-TYPE>`

Comment: Thank you! It was the replicaSets.

Comment: Hi @Shawlz please post it as an answer for visibility.

Comment: Hi @jt97, I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause could be either an existing deployment, replicaset, daemonset, statefulset or a static pod. Check if any of these exist in the affected namespace using `kubectl get <RESOURCE-TYPE>`

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen after issuing a `rollout restart deployment` while a pod was already in an error or creating state, and explicitly deleting the second pod only resulted in a new one getting scheduled (trick birthday candle situation).

I find almost any time I have an issue like this it can be fixed by simply zeroing out the `replicaSets` in the deployment, applying, then restoring `replicaSets` to the original value.